# the next() method in the Scanner doen't wait for input

Tags: java, exception

i wrote this line (String str = sc.next();) like 10 times in my code, and all of them work ok except for one that doesn't wait for my input and immediately throws an exception "java.util.NoSuchElementException" !
does any one have an idea why that could happen ??

```
private static Matrix GetRationalMatrix(int[] size) throws Exception {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    MathVector[] matrix = new MathVector[size[0]];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < size[0] ; i++) {
        MathVector vector = null;
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        str = str.replaceAll("[ \t]+", " ");
        String[] splitStr = str.split(" ");
        Scalar[] scalarVector = new Scalar[size[1]];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < splitStr.length ; j++) {
            String[] tmp = splitStr[j].split("/");
            try {
                scalarVector[j] = new Rational(Integer.parseInt(tmp[0]), Integer.parseInt(tmp[1]));
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                sc.close();
                throw new Exception("Please enter values properly: a/b were a,b are integers!");
            }
        }
        vector = new MathVector(size[1], scalarVector);
        matrix[i] = new MathVector(vector);
    }
    Matrix ans = new Matrix(size[0], matrix);
    sc.close();
    return ans;
}
```

in size[0] the number of rows and in size[1] number of columns , both will be positive integers

Comment: What's the value of `size[0]`?

Comment: Can you post the full code with correct syntax? You've left the for loop block open.

Comment: Show us the rest of the method. Also show us the exception stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

`nextLine(`) instead of `next();`

Both hasNext and next methods may block waiting for further input. Whether a hasNext method blocks has no connection to whether or not its associated next method will block.

Comment: Might this have different behavior than what was originally intended though? And I thought `next()` would block if it still needed input...

Comment: i replaced all `next();` with `nextLine();` but same problem
"java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found"

Answer (score 0):

If you previously used

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

inside a try-with-resources or closed the `Scanner` yourself, that would have closed the underlying `System.in` stream. In that case, trying to read from it again through a `Scanner` would cause a `NoSuchElementException`.

Don't close `System.in` and try to re-use the same `Scanner` object.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for `hasNext()` specifies:

> Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input. This method may block while waiting for input to scan. The scanner does not advance past any input.

The javadoc for `next()` specifies:

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

That does **not** mean `next()` will always block, but it might block, say if it's waiting for the *end* of the token, since it promises to return the next *complete* token from the input. Checking whether the input *contains* another token is an entirely different operation, performed by `hasNext()`, which will block because it will wait for input (until EOF is found).

So I think you're getting `NoSuchElementException` because you are using `next()` improperly.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.NoSuchElementException is a RuntimeException which can be thrown by different classes in Java like Iterator, Enumerator, Scanner or StringTokenizer. All of those classes has method to fetch next element or next tokens if underlying data-structure doesn't have any element Java throws "java.util.NoSuchElementException".

u can use a string tokenizer in our code..

StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(sc);

u can use hasMoretokens() method....so that it returns true as long as the input u provided have more tokens.....
 incase u want to get next token u can nextToken() method...